# Capturing browser information using log4net configuration settings

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, log4net

Is there any way to get user browser information in log4net? (i.e. information about the user's browser when the error/info/warning message was being logged by log4net.) I am looking for a built-in log4net configuration setting.

At the moment the message details logged by log4net look like this:

```
<log4net:event logger="MyApplication" timestamp="2013-11-08"
    level="ERROR" thread="708" domain="xx" identity="xxx" 
    username="xxx"><log4net:message>App_Error</log4net:message>
<log4net:properties>
    <log4net:data name="log4net:Identity" value="xxx" />
    <log4net:data name="log4net:UserName" value="xxx" />
    <log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="xxx" />
</log4net:properties>
<log4net:exception>Some error.</log4net:exception>
</log4net:event>
```

Can we capture the browser information so that the logged message looks something like the following (it doesnt have to be exactly in this format but as long as we can see the browser information with the error that will be helpful):

```
<log4net:event logger="MyApplication" timestamp="2013-11-08"
    level="ERROR" thread="708" domain="xx" identity="xxx" 
    username="xxx"><log4net:message>App_Error</log4net:message>
<log4net:properties>
    <log4net:data name="log4net:Identity" value="xxx" />
    <log4net:data name="log4net:UserName" value="xxx" />
    <log4net:data name="log4net:HostName" value="xxx" />
    <log4net:data name="log4net:Browser" value="Mozilla/Chrome/Firefox/IE/Ver 10..." />
</log4net:properties>
<log4net:exception>Some error.</log4net:exception>
</log4net:event>
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC with C#.

I googled it but didnt find anything. May be because there is no such setting.

Comment: There is no such setting. Your web app will have to determine the value, and [store it where log4net can find it](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx)

Comment: Post your comment as an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such setting. Your web app will have to determine the value, and [store it where log4net can find it](http://www.beefycode.com/post/Log4Net-Tutorial-pt-6-Log-Event-Context.aspx).